# How to increase the number of thumbnails images into FlexSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexslider, woothemes

I am using FlexSlider to display products. It has a control navigation which displays thumbnails below the main/focussed image.

I am working from this example:
http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-controlnav.html

The sample only allows 4 images, if you have more than 4 then it starts a new row for the thumbnails. How do I fit in more images into the thumbnails section? Maybe 6 images, or 8?

Answer (score 1):

```
  .flex-control-thumbs li {
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
}
```

Changing the width comes to mind.

Comment: changing the`% `to a pixel format :`100px` would be a normal width